# Hard-coded comparisons

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a calculator style spreadsheet for quickly and easily calculating normally tedious equations into a few simple clicks. However, I have hit a snag.

In B3 I have a list of various possible selections for the user. Depending on what they select, multitudes of other cells will change values to display the correct and needed information.

My first attempt to try to get a cell to format dependent upon the contents of B3 used:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Plate",B3)),"Quake",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cloth",B3)),"Ocean",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Leather",B3)),"Typhoon",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Neck",B3)),"Earth",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ring",B3)),"Earth",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dagger",B3)),"Mountain",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Sword",B3)),"Summer",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Katana",B3)),"Sky",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Club",B3)),"Autumn",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Shortspear",B3)),"Winter",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Axe",B3)),"Typhoon",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Greatsword",B3)),"Desert",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Nodachi",B3)),"Lightning",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Greataxe",B3)),"Desert",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Greatclub",B3)),"Sunset",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Longspear",B3)),"Squall",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Shield",B3)),"Quake",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bow",B3)),"Volcano",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Scepter",B3)),"Meadow",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Staff",B3)),"Ocean","")
```

The problem I had is that IF expects three arguments maximum.

Is there a way to circumvent this, possibly by breaking up the comparison using many OR statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `IF` statements. The syntax is indeed three arguments, say `=IF(test,a,z)`. So if the first test fails you may incorporate a second for that case: `=IF(test1,a,IF(test2,b,z))` and a third `=IF(test1,a,IF(test2,b,IF(test3,c,z)))` and so on.

Comment: This works exactly as I needed to. Thank you a ton, I am ashamed I didn't think of this sooner.